# Is there the equivalent of mongodb's oplog in arangodb?

Tags: meteor, arangodb

I'm trying to understand what it would take to efficiently use arangodb as a database for meteor. In that context I was wondering whether arangodb has the equivalent of mongodb's oplog that one could use to "subscribe" to all (or better yet select) updates to the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the replication API for this. All operations executed are logged in ArangoDB's write-ahead log. Its contents can be fetched via the HTTP REST API, via the endpoint `GET /_api/replication/logger-follow`. 
By passing the `from` URL parameter to this URL, you can make the API return changes from a certain point in the WAL. The response will then contain an HTTP header `x-arango-replication-lastincluded`, which will give you the highest tick value included in the response. For subsequent calls to the API, you can pass this value in the `from` parameter and somewhat *tail* the changelog.

The API description is [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/HTTP/Replications/ReplicationLogger.html).